# Import jquery's $ and export it

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I've read a few related questions but I don't understand very well why this wouldn't work:

```
//common.js

import {$} from "jquery";

const mytoggler = element => $(element).toggle();

export {$,mytoggler}
```

Whenever I `import {$,mytoggler} from './common.js';` I get an error from webpack (but probably this has to do with jquery as any other export/import runs fine):

```
Uncaught TypeError: _common_common_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.$ is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try exporting `$` as `jquery`, `const jquery = $; export {jquery}` , and when you import use `as`. `import { jquery as $ } from "./common"`

Comment: @Woohaik same error

Comment: `import $ from "jquery"` in common.js, instead of `{$}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the README description of the jquery module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Says that the correct way to include jquery is the following:

`import $ from "jquery";` instead of `import {$} from "jquery";`

Comment: yes, you're correct, thank you.